# mysql master/slave replication set up but non working

Tags: mysql, replication

I'm experiencing some trouble setting up mysql replication between a master & a slave..

I did the setup successfully, but data doesn't update.

Master : show master status;

```
[File]: mysql-bin.000033
[Position]: 1757196
[Binlog_Do_DB]: ciel
```

Master : show processlist;

```
[User]: slave
[Host]: 92.222.177.xxx:57578 ( right slave ip )
[db]: 
[Command]: Binlog Dump
[Time]: 1231
[State]: Has sent all binlog to slave; waiting for binlog to be updated
```

Slave : show slave status;

```
[Slave_IO_State]: Waiting for master to send event
[Master_Host]: 46.105.122.xxx
[Master_User]: slave
[Master_Port]: 3306
[Connect_Retry]: 60
[Master_Log_File]: mysql-bin.000033
[Read_Master_Log_Pos]: 1757196
[Relay_Log_File]: mysqld-relay-bin.000006
[Relay_Log_Pos]: 252
[Relay_Master_Log_File]: mysql-bin.000033
[Slave_IO_Running]: Yes
[Slave_SQL_Running]: Yes
[Replicate_Do_DB]: ciel
[Exec_Master_Log_Pos]: 1757196
[Relay_Log_Space]: 409
[Until_Condition]: None
[Master_SSL_Allowed]: No
[Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert]: No
[Master_Server_Id]: 1
```

Slave : show proccesslist;

```
[User]: system user
[Host]: 
[db]: 
[Command]: Connect
[Time]: 1231
[State]: Waiting for master to send event
[Info]: 

[Id]: 2
[User]: system user
[Host]: 
[db]: 
[Command]: Connect
[Time]: 1231
[State]: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for the slave I/O thread to update it
```

then selecting data on master :

```
master: lastmod: 2014-10-26 17:14:55
slave:  lastmod: 2014-10-26 15:45:45
```

I'm feeling lost, because I'm still not finding after 8 hours, how to set this up correctly.

Comment: Check your firewall rules? Check permissions for your replication users? Check for errors in the log?

Comment: Be careful with those _do_db variables if you don't connect to the named db as default database: http://www.percona.com/blog/2009/05/14/why-mysqls-binlog-do-db-option-is-dangerous/

Comment: How many relay-bin files do you have? And by what names? And what is the value of Seconds_behind_master in the slave status?

Comment: You'll get more traction on this in another group. Try **serverfault** instead.